# Hazelcast CacheManager fails in native Quarkus app

Tags: quarkus, hazelcast

I have a Camel Quarkus application that starts Hazelcast instance in embedded mode, and a custom cache policy that connects to the cache configured in that Hazelcast instance. Everything works fine in JVM mode, but in native mode it fails with the following exception:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at com.hazelcast.client.cache.impl.HazelcastClientCacheManager.findCacheConfig(HazelcastClientCacheManager.java:129)
        at com.hazelcast.cache.impl.AbstractHazelcastCacheManager.getCacheUnchecked(AbstractHazelcastCacheManager.java:228)
        at com.hazelcast.cache.impl.AbstractHazelcastCacheManager.getCache(AbstractHazelcastCacheManager.java:210)
        at com.hazelcast.cache.impl.AbstractHazelcastCacheManager.getCache(AbstractHazelcastCacheManager.java:65)
```

How do I go about troubleshooting it further? Is there anything I'm missing?

I tried adding a bunch of Hazelcast classes to my `reflection-config.json`, I have both `hazelcast.xml` and `hazelcast-client.xml` in my classpath and they are both listed in the `resources-config.json`.

The Hazelcast version I use is 5.1.3. Tried with 5.2.0, same issue.

Comment: If I recall correctly there is a Hazelcast extension, isn't there?

Comment: The extension is only for client, unfortunately. I tried it though, same issue.

Comment: Actually, if I understand the code correctly, the extension effectively disables the JCache (https://github.com/hazelcast/quarkus-hazelcast-client/blob/master/runtime/src/main/java/io/quarkus/hazelcast/client/runtime/graal/Target_JCacheDetector.java#L16). This causes NPE, because this call https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/master/hazelcast/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/client/cache/impl/HazelcastClientCacheManager.java#L73 returns null, because ProxyManager first calls JCacheDetector and it returns false.